# Multiple Drop-down's and click Styling Problems

Tags: jquery

I know adding this question is a long shot from anyone even wanting to answer due to having to wade through all my JQuery script to resolve any problems I am currently experiencing, however I do not know where else to look.

**Live View:** https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/Account/Management/PageBuilder/box.html

I have recently implemented so you can have more than one drop down with very slight modifications when you implement another, however I am having some problems doing the following;

- After clicking on input field:

  - The other input field looses it's on mouse over effects
  - Upon hovering over the drop down for the input field you have chosen, styles are then reverted
- Upon clicking on one input field, it's drop down, anywhere but the drop content then click in the other input field is broken.

This is my first really JQuery script whereas anything else I have done as mainly been snippets from here and there and whatnot. I don't know how to resolve these problems and I am, at this moment at a complete loss.

Thank you so very much for any time spent in helping and any help and/or advice you provide,

Best Regards,

Tim

Comment: Can't access the link!

Comment: You have a javascript error in box.html line 82.  You have "lert" instead of "alert".

Comment: Thank you @Lowkase this was meant to have been commented out.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?  Or are you still getting the described output?

Comment: @Lowkase I am not only still getting these problems occurring, however I have found another problem with the drop down button. It seems like it is ignoring 'lastCheck' or this is part of the greater problem, as if you have one drop down open anywhere you click other than the container it's in hides it like normal but not if you click on the other drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, lots of stuff going on here...

1) Why a mousedown and a click event handler on the same selector that essentially does the same thing?

2) instead of mouseover and mouseout, I would probably use hover, or try to use CSS only if all you are doing is modifying CSS.

3) var state = false; at line 85 is global, and cannot be uniquely used by multiple objects. If you need to set some state property on an individual element, use the data property of the element instead.

4) Remember, when using jQuery, you are normally dealing with a SET of matched elements, not just one. So you need to make sure you are dealing with the one element you want.

5) Just one example of how I might write one part of your code:

Instead of:

```
    $('.Row1 input:text').mouseover(function () {
        var thisParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        if (!FZTxtInputState) {
            $("#" + thisParent + " .DropBtn").css({
```

I would:

```
        $('.Row1 input:text').mouseover(function () {
            if (!FZTxtInputState) {
                $(this).closest(".DropBtn").css({
```

This won't solve all your problems, but I can at least see you are trying to learn jQuery!

Comment: +1 I did originally try to mainly use CSS/CSS3, however if you notice when you hover over the input, it also changes the drop button style and other problems were occurring whereas with JQuery I have achieved a lot more progress. The mousedown event is as the styles don't show on click instantly of which I would like them to and I did attempt to use .closest(), however I could not get this working. Regarding the global event, I need it to be global to pass from functions and I don't believe this conflicts anywhere, it just changes? Best Regards, Tim

Comment: Well, what I see is if(!state) on a handler like $('.DropBtn'). If that $('.DropBtn') can handle multiple elements on the page, then setting a global variable to handle it won't work. You will need to check a propety of the element that is unique to that element.

Comment: Ah, I now understand where you are coming from on this variable! I'll have a little play around and see if my current experience can resolve hits.

Comment: Due to suggestions I have restarted again.